# Cypress test Ownership

Tags: testing, cypress, circleci

I'm looking for a way to associated Cypress tests with a specific team.

For context, we have a monolithic application supported by ~10 teams. We have a Cypress test suite consisting of ~50 tests, and currently when tests fail we send alerts to a single slack channel. What we'd like to move to instead is to associate each of the 50 tests with a single development team, in order to be able to send failures to the appropriate team slack channel.

I'm accustomed to Python world of Pytest, where annotations and conftest.py can be used to build support for this.

Is there any 'best practice' for associating a test with a team?

Comment: @ebanster that would mean needing to run each team (implemented as a tag) individually, correct?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. The "sending to specific slack channels" would be tricky though. The other thing I can think of is to use "folder" inside cypress to categorise each teams then in your CI, you have separate builds / run for these folders and integrate appropriate slack channel to each.  Something like: `npx cypress run --spec "cypress/integration/team1/**/*.js"` `npx cypress run --spec "cypress/integration/team2/**/*.js"`. Sorry not familiar with Pytest so unable to provide a bit of comparison.